# $q.defer(), AngularJS1 $asyncValidators only matches the first object in the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-schema-form

```
{
  key: "username",
  $asyncValidators: {
    'asynch': function(username) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function(){
        for(var i=0; i<=RegUsers.users.length-1; i++) {
          console.log(RegUsers.users[i].username);
          //If username is present in RegUsers
          if(username === RegUsers.users[i].username) {
            console.log(username + " matches " + RegUsers.users[i].username);
            deferred.reject();
          }else {
             deferred.resolve();
          }//$timeout end
        } //for loop end
      }, 200);//
       return deferred.promise;
    }// asynch function end
  }, // $asyncValidators obj end
  validationMessage:  {
    'async': "Username Already Taken"
  }//validationMessage end
},//first obj end
```

Using Angular Schema Form, I am trying to create an async validation on the username input but the validation only works for the first matched object in the RegUsers.users array. This is a service I created which has a collection of user details. When looped through the 'async': function(username) matches and only validates the first object's username. It also does match the rest of the usernames but the form does not validate as required. For example:

```
RegUsers.users = [
  {
    username: "user1",
    email: "user1@gmail.com",
    message: "Hello, my name is user1 "
  },
  {
    username: "user2",
    email: "user2@gmail.com",
    message: "Hello, my name is user2 "
  },
  {
    username: "user3",
    email: "user3@gmail.com",
    message: "Hello, my name is user3 "
  },
  {
    username: "user4",
    email: "user4@gmail.com",
    message: "Hello, my name is user4 "
  }
];
```

In the form, if you enter user1 in the username input field, it will be validated and output the error message: "Username Already Taken". But if you enter user2, user3 or user4 none of these get validated but are matched against RegUsers.users, therefore the form stays $valid insted of $invalid. I don't know why it isn't functioning properly and also...

I am still learning angularJs and this is the first encounter with promises as I am following the [DOCS](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#asyncvalidators) on Angular Schema Form to validate the form I have constructed.

Comment: Please, if you don't solved this case yet, debug into a for loop the content of `username` and `console.log(RegUsers.users[i]`. Otherwise, please close the issue.